# What is Natural Language Processing Doing Exactly in This Code?

Tags: nlp

I am new to natural language processing and I want to use it to write a news aggregator(in Node.js in my case). Rather than just use a prepackage framework, I want to learn the nuts and bolts and I am starting with the NLP portion. I found this one tutorial that has been the most helpful so far:

http://www.p-value.info/2012/12/howto-build-news-aggregator-in-100-loc.html

In it, the author gets the RSS feeds and loops through them looking for the elements(or fields) `title` and `description`. I know Python and understand the code. But what I don't understand is what NLP is doing here with `title` and `description` under the hood(besides scraping and tokenizing, which is apparent...and those tasks don't need a NLP).

```
import feedparser
import nltk
corpus = []
titles=[]
ct = -1
for feed in feeds:
    d = feedparser.parse(feed)
    for e in d['entries']:
       words = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(nltk.clean_html(e['description']))
       words.extend(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(e['title']))
       lowerwords=[x.lower() for x in words if len(x) > 1]
       ct += 1
       print ct, "TITLE",e['title']
       corpus.append(lowerwords)
       titles.append(e['title'])
```

Comment: this question is pretty unclear. NLP is not something which do stuff. I think you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

(reading your question more carefully maybe this was all already obvious to you, but it doesn't look like anything more deep or interesting is going on)

`wordpunct_tokenize` is set up here [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html) (last line) as

```
wordpunct_tokenize = WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize
```

[WordPunctTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.regexp.WordPunctTokenizer) is [implemented](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html#WordPunctTokenizer) by this code:

```
class WordPunctTokenizer(RegexpTokenizer):
    def __init__(self):
        RegexpTokenizer.__init__(self, r'\w+|[^\w\s]+')
```

The heart of this is just the regular expression `r'\w+|[^\w\s]+'`, which defines what strings are considered to be tokens by this tokenizer. There are two options, separated by the `|`:

1. `\w+`, that is, more than one "word" character (alphabetical or numeric)
2. `[^\w\s]+`, more than one character that is not either a "word" character or whitespace, thus this matches any string of punctuation

[Here is a reference](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for Python regular expressions.

I have not dug into the RegexpTokenizer, but I assume is set up such that the `tokenize` function returns an iterator that searches a string for the first match of the regular expression, then the next, etc.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for..I already know about the parsing, tokenizing, regexp. I want to know how NLP is working here in the code and being applied...meaning the words, the tags(ie In/for), etc.